# Format date in elasticsearch query (during retrieval)

Tags: java, groovy, elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch index with a field "aDate" (and lot of other fields) with the following mapping

```
"aDate" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "date_optional_time"
}
```

When i query for a document i get a result like

```
"aDate" : 1421179734000,
```

I know this is the epoch, the internal java/elasticsearch date format, but i want to have a result like:

```
"aDate" : "2015-01-13T20:08:54",
```

I play around with scripting

```
{  
 "query":{  
   "match_all":{  

   }
 },
 "script_fields":{  
   "aDate":{  
      "script":"if (!_source.aDate?.equals('null')) new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd\\'T\\'HH:mm:ss').format(new java.util.Date(_source.aDate));"
   }
 }
}
```

but it give strange results (**script works basically, but aDate is the only field returned and _source is missing**). This looks like

```
"hits": [{
        "_index": "idx1",
        "_type": "type2",
        "_id": "8770",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "fields": {
            "aDate": ["2015-01-12T17:15:47"]
        }
    },
```

I would prefer a solution without scripting if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run a query in Elasticsearch you can request it to return the raw data, for example specifying [fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html):

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/myindex/date-test/_search?pretty -d '
{
 "fields" : "aDate",
 "query":{  
   "match_all":{  

   }
 }
}'
```

Will give you the date in the format that you originally stored it:

```
{
  "_index" : "myindex",
  "_type" : "date-test",
  "_id" : "AUrlWNTAk1DYhbTcL2xO",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "fields" : {
    "aDate" : [ "2015-01-13T20:08:56" ]
  }
}, {
  "_index" : "myindex",
  "_type" : "date-test",
  "_id" : "AUrlQnFgk1DYhbTcL2xM",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "fields" : {
    "aDate" : [ 1421179734000 ]
  }
```

It's not possible to change the date format unless you use a script.

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/myindex/date-test/_search?pretty -d '
{  
 "query":{  
   "match_all":{ }
 },
 "script_fields":{  
   "aDate":{  
      "script":"use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) { new Date( doc[\"aDate\"].value )  }"
   }
 }
}'
```

Will return:

```
{
  "_index" : "myindex",
  "_type" : "date-test",
  "_id" : "AUrlWNTAk1DYhbTcL2xO",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "fields" : {
    "aDate" : [ "2015-01-13T20:08:56.000Z" ]
  }
}, {
  "_index" : "myindex",
  "_type" : "date-test",
  "_id" : "AUrlQnFgk1DYhbTcL2xM",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "fields" : {
    "aDate" : [ "2015-01-13T20:08:54.000Z" ]
  }
}
```

To apply a format, append it as follows:

```
"script":"use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ){ new Date( doc[\"aDate\"].value ).format(\"yyyy-MM-dd\")   }"
```

will return `"aDate" : [ "2015-01-13" ]`

To display the `T`, you'll need to use quotes but replace them with the Unicode equivalent:

```
"script":"use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ){ new Date( doc[\"aDate\"].value ).format(\"yyyy-MM-dd\u0027T\u0027HH:mm:ss\") }"
```

returns `"aDate" : [ "2015-01-13T20:08:54" ]`

---

### To return script_fields and source

Use **_source** in your query to specify the fields you want to return:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/myindex/date-test/_search?pretty -d '
 {  "_source" : "name",
  "query":{
    "match_all":{ }
  },
  "script_fields":{
    "aDate":{
       "script":"use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) { new Date( doc[\"aDate\"].value )  }"
    }
  }
 }'
```

Will return my `name` field:

```
"_source":{"name":"Terry"},
  "fields" : {
    "aDate" : [ "2015-01-13T20:08:56.000Z" ]
  }
```

Using asterisk will return all fields, e.g.:  `"_source" : "*",`

```
"_source":{"name":"Terry","aDate":1421179736000},
  "fields" : {
    "aDate" : [ "2015-01-13T20:08:56.000Z" ]
  }
```

Comment: thanks. since original date format is epoch i have to use the script. How can i get a result which includes also _source? (see bold marked text in the question)

Comment: I've updated the answer to include using _source to bring back other fields.

Comment: great, that work. If i use "_source" : "*" i get all source fields, thats what i wanted

Comment: use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) don't seem to work with ES 2.2. Any idea, (lang is groovy)?  No such property: groovy for class: 05c0662f39d36342a9a0a646db3aa789da16c191

Comment: this no longer works in 7.4....

Answer (score 7):

Since 5.0.0, es use `Painless` as script language: [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/modules-scripting-groovy.html)

Try this (work in 6.3.2)

```
"script":"doc['aDate'].value.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking EVERYWHERE for this.

Answer (score 4):

As [LabOctoCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931241/format-date-in-elasticsearch-query-during-retrieval#comment58587369_27932753) mentioned, [Olly Cruickshank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931241/format-date-in-elasticsearch-query-during-retrieval/27932753#27932753) answer no longer works in elastic 2.2. I changed the script to:

```
"script":"new Date(doc['time'].value)"
```

You can format the date according to [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)).

Comment: not working in 6.x. Since 5.0.0, es use `Painless` as script language

Answer (score 1):

Scripting it only computes the answer when the row is extracted.  This is expensive, and keeps you from using any date-related search functions in Elasticsearch.

You should create an elasticsearch "date" field before inserting it.  Looks like a java Date() object [will do](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/bulk.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Archon for your suggestion. I used your answer as a guide to remove the time element from a datetime field in Elasticsearch

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "grp_by_date": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 200,
                "script": "doc['TransactionReconciliationsCreated'].value.toString('yyyy-MM-dd')"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Elasticsearch 7, and want to display datetime in a specified timezone, you can request it like this

```json
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "client": {
              "value": "iOS",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "time": {
      "script": "ZonedDateTime input = doc['time'].value; input = input.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of('Asia/Shanghai')); String output = input.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME); return output"
    }
  },
  "_source": true,
```

return

```
{
...
        "_source" : {
          ...
          "time" : 1632903354213
...
        },
        "fields" : {
          "time" : [
            "2021-09-29T16:15:54.213+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]"
          ]
        }
      },
...
}
```