# change the format returned from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way I can instruct ES to return the date in a specific format? 
I'd love to have the result you see below as this:

```
{ items[
   { image: ‘url’, title: ‘hello there' },
   { image: ‘url’, title: ‘hello there' } 
  ] 
}
```

I'm doing an ES query which returns this:

```
{
  // snipp...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 0.124633156,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "harvester",
      "_type" : "entries",
      "_id" : "5555b05750c4c81f97e669b9",
      "_score" : 0.124633156,
      "_source":{
          "title": "hello there",
          "image": "http://example.com/img.png""}
    }, {
      "_index" : "harvester",
      "_type" : "mongodb",
      "_id" : "5555b05750c4c81f97e669b9",
      "_score" : 0.124633156,
      "_source": {
         "description": "long desc",
         "url":   "http://example.com""
      }
    }, {
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date in elasticsearch query (during retrieval)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931241/format-date-in-elasticsearch-query-during-retrieval)

Comment: I don't see any dates in your examples, but details of how to format dates in a response are given here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931241/format-date-in-elasticsearch-query-during-retrieval/27932753#27932753

Comment: @OllyCruickshank the proper way of pointing to your answer is to mark the current post as "duplicate of..." ;-).