# Insert date as epoch_seconds, output as formatted date

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, formatting

I have a set of timestamps formatted as seconds since the epoch. I'd like to insert to ElasticSearch as `epoch_seconds` but when querying would like to see the output as a pretty date, e.g. `strict_date_optional_time`.

My below mapping preserves the format that the input came in - is there any way to normalize the output to just one format via the [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) api?

Current Mapping:

```
PUT example
{
  "mappings": {
    "time": {
      "properties": {
        "time_stamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example docs

```
POST example/time
{
  "time_stamp": "2018-03-18T00:00:00.000Z"
}

POST example/time
{
  "time_stamp": "1521389162" // Would like this to output as: 2018-03-18T16:05:50.000Z
}
```

GET example/_search output:

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "time_stamp": "1521389162", // Stayed as epoch_second
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "time_stamp": "2018-03-18T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931241/format-date-in-elasticsearch-query-during-retrieval You can modify the output of the date using a script. If you still have issues, please let me know, I can post an answer

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou It looks like the default scripting language is now Painless, so the syntax is a bit different. Is there a way to do this without using scripts? The below code works, though, since it appears that the default .value attribute formats as ISO.
```"script_fields": {
    "date": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['time_stamp'].value"
      }
    }
  }```

Comment: As pointed the linked question, I think it is not possible to achieve this without using scripts. That would have been a great feature, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch differentiates between the `_source` and the so called *stored fields*. The first one is supposed to represent your input.

If you actually use stored fields (by specifying `store=true` in your mapping) then specify [multiple date formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) this is easy: (emphasis mine)

> Multiple formats can be specified by separating them with || as a separator. Each format will be tried in turn until a matching format is found. **The first format will be used to convert the milliseconds-since-the-epoch value back into a string.**

I have tested this with elasticsearch 5.6.4 and it works fine:

```
PUT /test -d '{ "mappings": {"doc": { "properties": {"post_date": {
    "type":"date",
    "format":"basic_date_time||epoch_millis",
    "store":true
} } } } }'

PUT /test/doc/2 -d '{                                                                                                                            
    "user" : "test1",
    "post_date" : "20150101T121030.000+01:00"
}'

PUT /test/doc/1 -d '{                                                                                                                            
    "user" : "test2",
    "post_date" : 1525167490500
}'
```

Note how two different input-formats will result in the same format when using `GET /test/_search?stored_fields=post_date&pretty=1`

```
{
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "post_date" : [
            "20150101T111030.000Z"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "post_date" : [
            "20180501T093810.500Z"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

If you want to change the input (in `_source`) you're not so lucky, the [mapping-transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-transform.html) feature has been removed:

> This was deprecated in 2.0.0 because it made debugging very difficult. As of now there really isn’t a feature to use in its place other than transforming the document in the client application.

If, instead of changing the stored data you are interested in formatting the output, have a look at [this answer to *Format date in elasticsearch query (during retrieval)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932753/3749523)